# iOS Crash Report SKProductsRequest

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, crash-reports, skproduct

Could someone confirm my thinking that the following crash report would be generated due to `SKProductsRequestDelegate` still being allocated, yet the code itself not being? i.e. the VC has been closed?

```
StoreKit: __34-[SKProductsRequest _handleReply:]_block_invoke + 442

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x41682340
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x38d19626 objc_msgSend + 6
1   StoreKit                        0x30c4784a __34-[SKProductsRequest _handleReply:]_block_invoke + 442
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x391f7830 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 8
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x391f781c _dispatch_client_callout + 20
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x391fe49a _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 274
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2e45f89c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 4
6   CoreFoundation                  0x2e45e170 __CFRunLoopRun + 1296
7   CoreFoundation                  0x2e3c8eba CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
8   CoreFoundation                  0x2e3c8c9e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
9   GraphicsServices                0x3332265e GSEventRunModal + 134
10  UIKit                           0x30d15148 UIApplicationMain + 1132
11  BaseApp                         0x00035aea 0x2c000 + 39658
12  libdyld.dylib                   0x3921cab4 start + 0
```

If my thinking is correct, can I resolve this by calling:-

```
request.delegate = nil;
[request cancel];
request = nil;
```

If I am incorrect, could someone shed some more light on this for me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For ref, my addition of the following code did indeed rectify the issue.

```
request.delegate = nil;
[request cancel];
request = nil;
```

Comment: Where did you put that?  Don't understand.

Comment: Add it as the class is being removed, so viewWillDisappear, dealloc, or any backgrounding.

Comment: Ah ya I got it. Eventually I realized that object was just deallocing while the call was being made so I moved it. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. It seems SKProductRequest stores the delegate in an ivar while processing the response, thus nil'ing the delegate at `-request:didReceiveResponse:` does not help. I resorted to storing the response object and dispatching at `-requestDidFinish:` delegate instead

Comment: @Voxar, can you show me that code snippet for requestDidFinish